# Как можно заменить данный код с синхронным AJAX

Tags: ajax, javascript, xmlhttprequest

Добрый день! У меня есть следующий объект **ajax** с методом **json**:

```
var ajax = {
    json: function(url, data, callback, async, presend, aftersend, onprogress, error)       {
        if (typeof presend === 'function') presend();

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', url, async ? true : false);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        if (typeof aftersend === 'function') xhr.onload = aftersend;
        if (typeof onprogress === 'function') xhr.onprogress = onprogress;

        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                } else if (typeof error === 'function') {
                    error(xhr);
                }
            }
        }

        xhr.send(data);
    }
}
```

Я хочу при помощи ajax подгружать отдельные html-формы и помещать их в отдельный объект (помещать если не были добавлены ранее, если уже есть, то будут браться из объекта).

```
getUi: function(uiName) {
    if (!ui.forms.hasOwnProperty(uiName)) {
        var url = '/ui/' + encodeURIComponent(uiName);
        var form = '';
        ajax.json(url, null, function(json) {
            if (json.success) {
                 ui.forms[uiName] = json.form;
                         //return ui.forms[uiName];
            }
        }, false); //async = false
    }
    if (typeof ui.forms[uiName] !== 'undefined') {
        return ui.forms[uiName];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Так вот: если я использую синхронный AJAX, то все работает нормально, если же асинхронный, то я не могу возвратить полученные AJAX данные.

Вопрос: Стоит ли использовать синхронный AJAX, если не стоит, то как такое можно сделать с асинхронным вариантом?

Всем спасибо

Comment: что-то типа того:

    ajax.json(url, null, function(ui) {return function(json) {....}}(ui),true);

отпишитесь если это то что нужно,

Comment: К сожалению, тот же самый эффект...

Comment: var ui = {
 forms: {},

 getUi: function(uiName) {
  if (!ui.forms.hasOwnProperty(uiName)) {
   var url = '/ui/' + encodeURIComponent(uiName);
   var form = '';
   /*ajax.json(url, null, function(json) {
    if (json.success) {
     ui.forms[uiName] = json.form;
    }
   }, false);*/
   ajax.json(url, null, function(ui) {
    return function(json) {
     console.log(json);
     ui.forms[uiName] = json.form;
     return ui.forms[uiName];
    }
   }(ui), true);
  }
  console.log(ui.forms);
  if (typeof ui.forms[uiName] !== 'undefined') {
   return ui.forms[uiName];
  }
  return false;
 }
  }

Comment: можете сократить до jsfiddle ? а вообще проблема в том что `console.log(ui.forms);` и `return` отрабатывает до  окончания загрузки ? тогда вам нужно не получать данные из getUi, а передавать туда параметром функцию callback, т.к. `return ui.forms[uiName];` в callback запроса вообще неизвестно куда должен возвращать данные,

Comment: Да, конечно.. http://jsfiddle.net/H4fem/

Comment: [вариант 1](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/H4fem/2/) [вариант 2](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/H4fem/3/) (я там забыл поставить sync как опцию для ajax, но в целом все должно быть и так понятно)